# Formatting in equations

Tags: equations

I need to display 3 equations in the following format: [image]

What I am getting is 
[image]

The code is as below

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{Equ.3.3}
V'=e^{(ja)}\times V
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{Equ.3.4}
=[\cos(a) + j \times \sin(a)] \times (x+j \times y)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{Equ.3.5}
=x \cdot \cos(a) - y\cdot \sin(a) + j \cdot [x \cdot \sin(a) + y \cdot     \cos(a)]
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Could you please suggest how to achieve the desired results.

Comment: don't code these as separate `equation`s.  instead, use the `align` environment provided by `amsmath`, ending each line by `\\ ` and placing a `&` just before each `=` sign.  check the user's guide for other multi-line display structures (`texdoc amsmath`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the align environment like follows. The & character places an alignment vertical anchor for the align environment.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Each step of the expression can be referenced easily~\eqref{Equ.3.3},~\eqref{Equ.3.4} and~\eqref{Equ.3.5}.
\begin{align}
V' &=e^{(ja)}\times V \label{Equ.3.3}\\
&=[\cos(a) + j \times \sin(a)] \times (x+j \times y) \label{Equ.3.4}\\
&=x \cdot \cos(a) - y\cdot \sin(a) + j \cdot [x \cdot \sin(a) + y \cdot     \cos(a)] \label{Equ.3.5}
\end{align}
But I would say that usually one just labels the final result~\eqref{Equ.3}.
\begin{align}
V' &=e^{(ja)}\times V \nonumber\\
&=[\cos(a) + j \times \sin(a)] \times (x+j \times y) \nonumber\\
&=x \cdot \cos(a) - y\cdot \sin(a) + j \cdot [x \cdot \sin(a) + y \cdot     \cos(a)] \label{Equ.3}
\end{align}
Likewise, in a single-line environment we can achieve the same~\eqref{Equ.3b}. In this case though, the label is at the mid-height of the aligned box by default.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
V' &=e^{(ja)}\times V \\
&=[\cos(a) + j \times \sin(a)] \times (x+j \times y) \\
&=x \cdot \cos(a) - y\cdot \sin(a) + j \cdot [x \cdot \sin(a) + y \cdot     \cos(a)]
\end{aligned}
\label{Equ.3b}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help... That is exactly how I want.. Because of the requirements of the document I am making, I have to label them separately.. Could you please tell me which book or online link contains all these suggestions about how a document should be formatted

Comment: Tricky question that one. A comprehensive guide to 'some' of a document typesetting options is provided in the Chicago Manual of Style. I refer to this one, although some stuff is regulated by my University,  or via appropriate templates with a basic skeleton, say for a conference or journal articles, while others are left to the writer's discretion. [Wikibooks LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) is a good place to look for answers to questions like these.

Comment: @JoaoAndrade -- a slightly different way to attach only one number to a "continued" equation is to use `aligned` (a sub-environment) within the `equation` environment.  all documented in the `amsmath` user's guide (`texdoc amsmath` or go to "texdoc online" at http://www.texdoc.net/).  i've also noticed that the advice at wikibooks latex does not always follow "best practices".

Comment: @barbarabeeton, did not know about the aligned as a sub-enviroment. Usually I have to deal with one lined formulae not multiple lines. When multiple lines come, align is what I have used throughout. Maybe I should rephrase the Wikibooks suggestion. It is good for ad hoc solutions like this one, not for typesetting guidelines. As to best practices, you might be right, but it used to be where I looked up syntax for subfigures, minipages and the likes, and it served me right, hence the suggestion. Now, I just 'grep' into my previous documents.