# Curling equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, align, alignment

Could someone please tell me how I could curl equations? I am specifically looking to do the following:

```
EQUATION = EQUATION
         = EQUATION
         = EQUATION
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You'll want to use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package. There are many, many posts on this site on the topic.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please post it as an answer? I could then mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in my comment above, use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package. Please search this site if you need more help because help with aligning equations is a very common question that we get (e.g., [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262362/formatting-in-equations)).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Aligned equations:
\begin{align}
    A &= B\\
    &= C\\
    &= D
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `align*` if you don't want numbering.

Comment: In my opinion `equation` and `split` are better for such an application.